# Numpy matrix inversion gives wrong results for order greater than 18

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing a problem in inverting a matrix with `NumPy`. Strangely, it gives correct results only up till order 18. As soon as the order becomes greater than 18, it gives erroneous results.

```py
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy.matlib

I_1=np.matlib.eye(ngrid,ngrid,k=0,dtype=Decimal)
I_2=np.matlib.eye(ngrid,ngrid,k=1,dtype=Decimal)
I_3=np.matlib.eye(ngrid,ngrid,k=2,dtype=Decimal)

B=I_1 + 10.*I_2 + I_3
B=np.divide(B,12.)

B_inv=np.linalg.inv(B)
print B_inv

C=B.dot(B_inv)
print C
```

The last line was included to check whether it gave the correct result.

Comment: Pleas provide a minimal working example. When I copy the code, ngrid is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is technically nothing wrong with your code. However, you are running into a very fundamental issue in numerical analysis. There are two effects at play here:

1. Floating point errors
2. The condition number of a problem

I won’t explain them here, because virtually any introductory book on numerical analysis (e.g. [Kendall Atkinson](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/34629080/An_introduction_to_numerical_analysis__atkinson.pdf?1409843152=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DAN_INTRODUCTION_TO_NUMERICAL_ANALYSIS_Se.pdf&Expires=1602401769&Signature=DRZVTMWqlBK-iIwLoLcLvvm9VRZ-MI2BvY4NQ6AVH2WpshyG84K59BOfcrKvT5s-HNPixC4e%7Ehtt9WkmHkl56vul260vNvgNyjh-fGnbn9DI5pBJ0nK8W2kkcU6wfZ3jkgE8h68urQxd6LHZlB7tj95XGGGAr6%7E0k3PMmC1-FMprfMxkXxTteVfPIiut3JMpCK7qvxjaNp7MhGUa0MWQ8qwpgV8zVifkAOM-dJfSBSke2Rn8CIBTIGPs-1RwNeJy-Ng8Q0WM6QrhVzClYodiwxSyUbJ1oSdSiaUpNj64KYm66Xa1gBn8fLGBBVnXYIH2wjpt58jdabyMjJNpIVuPEw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)) does a better job than I could do here. I’ll only leave you with this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

NGRID = 8


def HilbertMatrix(N, dtype=np.float64):
    arr = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            arr[i,j] = 1 / (i + j + 1)
    return arr


H = HilbertMatrix(NGRID)
J = np.linalg.inv(H)

C = np.dot(H, J)

print(np.allclose(C, np.eye(NGRID)))
print(np.linalg.norm(C))
```

Try playing around with NGRID and see how far away C will be from the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks AlexNe. Sorry for the inconvenience caused by me. Actually ngrid is the number of rows/columns, so that these are the matrices of order ngrid^2. But your solution doesn't help. If ngrid is greater than 18,

Comment: the product B.dot(B_inv) does not produce a unit matrix.

Comment: I think I’m getting on to what you’re referring to. I’d suggest you do two things: 1. Invert ever larger [Hilbert Matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) and 2. Read the Wikipedia Article about [condition numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number)

Answer (score 0):

This is a a numerical analysis issue.

You're holding decimal objects in your numpy array for some reason, and this gets converted into the Object dtype. When you try to perform matrix inversion, the matrix gets converted into float (I'm guessing with low precision).

The condition number of a matrix helps us understand how hard it is to invert the matrix (see wikipedia for a more formal definition). If you check B using np.linalg.cond (make sure to convert to a numpy dtype first) you will see the condition number is around 1e18 (which is very very high).

Another way you can think of it if you know some linear algebra - the determinant of a matrix allows us to determine whether the matrix is singular or not. Det(B) = 0 means the matrix is singular. In your case you created a matrix for which calculating the determinant is very easy (upper triangular).

The matrix is upper triangular, for which the determinant is simply the product of the diagonal, which is (1/12)**(n_grid). This is why as ngrid grows, the matrix is nearly singular, and for the floating point precision you have (which I'm guessing gets converted to 16 under the hood), the matrix is essentially singular / non-invertible.

If you fix your code, which I took the liberty of doing, the implicit np dtype is float64, and the inversion works as desired.

I took the liberty of slightly modifying your code to make it work (ngrid wasn't defined) (changed ngrid to 19 to check).

```
import numpy as np
ngrid = 19
I_1 = np.eye(ngrid, ngrid, k=0)
I_2 = np.eye(ngrid, ngrid, k=1)
I_3 = np.eye(ngrid, ngrid, k=2)
B = I_1 + 10.*I_2 + I_3
B = np.divide(B, 12.)
print(np.linalg.cond(B))
B_inv = np.linalg.inv(B)
C = B.dot(B_inv)
assert np.diag(C).sum() == ngrid
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. I also suspected that numerical error was the real issue. But determinant is not the issue. If we remove the obnoxious division by 12 from my program, the determinant becomes 1 but condition number does not improve.Now I have to think how I can circumvent this difficulty. If anyone can suggest how to invert an ill-conditioned matrix, I will be very much obliged.

Comment: There are iterative schemes (e.g. Gauß-Seidel Method), but I couldn’t find any libraries implementing those.